# How to rename changelog files in Liquibase?

Tags: liquibase

I'm using Liquibase for my project and would like to rename my changelog files.

From old structure:

```
databaseChangeLog:
    - include:
        file: db/changelog/add_pokemons.sql
    - include:
        file: db/changelog/add_minions.sql
```

To new structure:

```
databaseChangeLog:
    - include:
        file: db/changelog/v001__add_table_pokemons.sql
    - include:
        file: db/changelog/v002__add_table_minions.sql
```

The Liquibase documentation unfortunately does not state best practices for such intention.

I was thinking about duplicating my files so I have the old ones plus new ones in one directory and then write a migration to change column `filename` in the `databasechangelog` table.

What would be the best approach in your opinion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that liquibase holds the name of file inside `databasechangelog.filename`. So if you are not using [logicalFilePath](https://docs.liquibase.com/concepts/changelogs/attributes/logicalfilepath.html) yet maybe you have a chance.

If those files you've posted are formatted sql files then you could do something like this (example for file `db/changelog/add_pokemons.sql`):

```
--liquibase formatted sql logicalFilePath:db/changelog/add_pokemons.sql
```

and you can rename the actual file to whatever you want.

In that case nothing should be broken inside existing databasechangelog table.

Other than that there is probably no available change that will do that automatically from liquibase.